# com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: tableName is an undefined name

Tags: db2, websphere-7

Our code is running in Websphere Application Server 7.0.0.37 and it is connecting to couple of DB2 databases. Occasionally we are getting the exception "com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: "SCHEMA.TABLENAME" is an undefined name".This is happening everyday when the load is particularly high. Please advise if this has to do anything with the connection settings in websphere. Below is the stacktrace:

> [4/6/16 21:54:08:083 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: "SCHEMA.TABLENAME" is an undefined
>   name. [4/6/16 21:54:08:083 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.zc.e(zc.java:1606) [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT]
>   000000f7 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.zc.a(zc.java:1206)
>   [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.eb.h(eb.java:149) [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7
>   SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.eb.a(eb.java:43) [4/6/16
>   21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.r.a(r.java:30) [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7
>   SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tb.g(tb.java:152) [4/6/16
>   21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.zc.n(zc.java:1186) [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT]
>   000000f7 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.db(ad.java:1761)
>   [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.d(ad.java:2203) [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT]
>   000000f7 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.W(ad.java:1276)
>   [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.execute(ad.java:1260) [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT]
>   000000f7 SystemErr     R  at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:942)
>   [4/6/16 21:54:08:084 PDT] 000000f7 SystemErr     R    at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:618)

Comment: Yes there is a table with that name. Application is just executing select and insert in that table. This is executed as part of processing a message from MDB

Comment: Hi mustaccio, Can you please edit your comment above to remove the table name. I am not sure if this is a security related stuff in my organization. Thanks for understanding

Comment: Well, you say there is such a table, but DB2 says there is not. Who do we trust?

Answer (score 0):

Connection settings in WebSphere Application Server can impact the schema that is used (based on the user name of the connection), however, it would be consistent and not vary based on whether or not a database is under load.  If you've observed that the problem occurs under load, but not otherwise, it's possible there could be a threading bug.

To clarify the problem,
Is SCHEMA.TABLENAME the schema and table that you expect to be used?  If not, which part is unexpected - the schema, the table name, or both?  Alternately, if SCHEMA.TABLENAME is expected, do queries to this same schema/table work when not under load?  Is the SCHEMA schema specified explicitly in the application, or implicitly from the connection username or data source settings?

Comment: The schema and table name are the right ones. The schema name is specified explicitly in the application code and not in the datasource settings. Can you please edit your answere to change the schema and table name to "SCHEMA.TABLENAME" as i am not sure of the security constraints in my organization.

Comment: Sure, I updated it accordingly.  Given what you said about the application hard coding the schema/table name, the only way I could explain this occurring would be that you are somehow ending up with connection with the wrong user which doesn't have access to that schema/table.  You could investigate that by trapping the error when it occurs, and then try this:
connection.getMetaData().getUserName()